# Why does nx.draw_networkx_edges not connect the nodes when plotting graph edges?

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I have a graph  `G` that I want to plot. `G` is a spatial directed graph and my nodes therefore have specific coordinates I want to plot them at. The graph is built from a morphological skeleton of an image using `sknw.build_sknw` from [here](https://github.com/Image-Py/sknw/blob/6c1b0dadea469b8cc25030f2bfb9b677426ee1ea/sknw/sknw.py#L120) (but I assume that it doesn't play a significant role).
However, when plotting, I am encountering some edge-connectivity problems where some edges between two neighboring nodes do not connect in the plot. They point in the right direction but are too short. However, this only happens with some edges. Most are visualized correctly:

[image: edges not connecting nodes]

Here is a minimum example with 3 nodes and 2 edges that reproduces the error:

I am reading in the Graph from an edgelist via:

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('test.edgelist', data=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

`test.edgelist` looks as follows:

```
2789 2762 {'pts': [[697, 259], [698, 259], [699, 259], [700, 259], [701, 259], [702, 259], [703, 259], [704, 259], [705, 259]], 'weight': 8.0}
2789 2823 {'pts': [[708, 264], [707, 265], [706, 266], [706, 267], [706, 268], [706, 269], [705, 270], [704, 271], [703, 272], [702, 273], [701, 274], [700, 275], [699, 275], [698, 275], [697, 275], [696, 275], [695, 276], [695, 277], [695, 278], [695, 279], [695, 280], [695, 281], [695, 282], [696, 283], [697, 284], [697, 285], [697, 286], [697, 287], [698, 288], [698, 289], [699, 290], [699, 291], [699, 292], [699, 293], [700, 294], [700, 295], [701, 296], [701, 297], [701, 298], [702, 299], [702, 300], [703, 301], [704, 302], [705, 303], [706, 304], [707, 305], [707, 306], [708, 307], [708, 308], [709, 309], [710, 309], [711, 310], [712, 310], [713, 310]], 'weight': 62.94112549695427}
```

The list of 'pts' corresponds to the pixels of the original morphological skeleton (in white in the first image) that are between two intersections (aka nodes from my graph).

I use `nx.draw_networkx_edges` and `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` to plot my graph. I define the layout with a dictionary of coordinates `coord_dict` that looks like this:

```
coord_dict = {'2789': [707, 261], '2823': [714, 311], '2762': [695, 259]}
```

Now, whenever I plot my graph with the following code:

```
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=coord_dict, arrows=True, arrowstyle='->', edge_color='green', arrowsize=0.75, width=0.45, ax=ax)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=coord_dict, node_size=0.15, node_color='red')
```

I get a plot like this, where the edges do not connect to the second node:
[image: networkx drawing error]

I've figured out, that when not plotting the edges via `arrows=False`, the straight edges WILL connect. However, the arrows are important for my visualisations and I would therefore appreciate any help on overcoming this plotting issue. Plus, I would like to understand the general issue on why some arrows will connect correctly, while others don't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the edges and nodes are being generated independently, and manually setting sizes and widths can lead to having having nodes slightly separated from the edges. If you don't need to draw them separately, just do it via a single call to `nx.draw`:

```
nx.draw(G, pos=coord_dict, 
        arrowstyle='->', 
        arrowsize=20, 
        width=2,
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=500, 
        node_color='orange',
        edge_color='green')
```

[image]

Alternatively, same as you where doing but avoid customising the node and arrow sizes:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
ax = plt.gca()
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=coord_dict, arrows=True, arrowstyle='->', 
                       edge_color='green', width=2, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=coord_dict, node_color='orange')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=coord_dict)
plt.box(False)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, this solved my specific problem, thank you!
However, it doesn't really explain why it was only an issue with some of the nodes/edges, and not all of them. Also, the distance from the arrowhead to the node center that it should have connected, varied strongly within one graph-plot. Do you know why this problem only exists in some cases?

Comment: Yes that is quite weird. The size should be proportional in all graph, so I don't really know. My guess is that it still has to do with setting the sizes manually. There might be a scale factor, and by having set sizes lower than `1`, the result might vary between objcets. But just a guess. I'd go with one of these approaches @sara