# How to create arrow in this ego network?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networking, networkx

```
import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'),
                  ('B', 'C'), ('E', 'F'),
                  ('D', 'E'), ('A', 'D'),
                  ('D', 'C'), ('C', 'F'),
                  ('D', 'E')])

ego = 'A'

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos, node_color="lavender",
        node_size=800, with_labels=True)

options = {"node_size": 1200, "node_color": "r"}

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[ego], **options)

plt.show()
```

`

I want to create arrows for the ego networks.
[I want it like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfo6F.jpg)
[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVegs.png)

I did not try anything cause I do not know how to add arrows.

Comment: Refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385340/why-does-nx-draw-networkx-edges-not-connect-the-nodes-when-plotting-graph-edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show **arrows** you might define: `arrows=True` and `arrowstyle`

**UPDATE**: the edges must be rearranged to match the draft you put here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfo6F.jpg

```
import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'),('A', 'D'),
                  ('B', 'C'), 
                  ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'F'),
                  ('D', 'E'),
                  ('F', 'E')])

ego = 'A'

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos, node_color="lavender",
        arrows=True, arrowstyle='-|>',    #   <-- Add this one
        node_size=800, with_labels=True)

options = {"node_size": 1200, "node_color": "r"}

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[ego], **options)

plt.show()
```

**Result**:

[image]